# Являются ли по происхождению старославянизмами слова?

Tags: этимология

Колокол, наказание, плеть, заклятая, клажа, часовня, церковь, храм, пономарь, дивный, набат, вопль.

Answer (score 1):

**Колокол** - исконно русское, клаколъ -
    ст.-слав.;
**Наказание** - производное
    от ст.-слав. "казати" - "говорить",
   ср. указ, приказ, отказ, рассказ;

**Плеть** было и в др.-русском и в
    ст.-слав., т.е. общеславянское

**Заклятая** от ст.-слав. клѧтва

**Клажа** от ст.слав. "класти". "кладу";

**Часовня** произошло от общеславянсого
        "часъ", современное значение
        (молельня с иконами без алтаря)
        слово приобрело в 14 веке, до этого
        времени оно означало сооружение, где
        водружались часы с боем или колокол,
        в который отбивали часы;

**Церковь** -
        русское, от др.-рус. цьркы, род. п.
        цьркъве, ст.-слав. - црькы.;

**Храм** -
        славянизм, русск. - хоромы

**Пономарь**
        - иск. русское;

**Дивный** - производное от диво -
    общеславянское;

**Набат** -
        слово арабского происхождения;

**Вопль**
        - от ст.-славянского въпль.